# Какой есть готовый модуль для выбора файлов из Google Диска?

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive, scripts

Написал вручную функцию выбора файлов из Google Диска - отправили назад из-за того, что очень долго работает и для этого есть готовый модуль. Не могу его найти. Подскажите, какой?

Answer (score 0):

Нашелся этот модуль ,если кому нужно : Google Picker API